# Can we convert List<Map<String, Object>> to Map<Object, Map<String, Object>> using groupby of Stream API

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a List of `List<Map<String, Object>>` like this

```html
[{"A": 2616100,
      "B": 2616100,
      "C": 31,
      "D": "Sold Promissory Buyer"
    },
    {
      "A": 101322143.24,
      "B": 50243301.2,
      "C": 569,
      "D": "Auction"
    },
    {
      "A": 72000,
      "B": 93900,
      "C": 1,
      "D": "Sold Third Party"
    }]
```

Using Stream API with groupBy method `salesReportForSoldProperty.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(tags -> tags.get("D")))`, I am able to get collection `Map<Object, List<Map<String, Object>>>`
 
But when I am trying to create JSON of this collection, I am getting Json like this

```html
  {
  "Sold Promissory Buyer": [
    {
      "A": 2616100,
      "B": 2616100,
      "C": 31,
      "D": "Sold Promissory Buyer"
    }
  ],
  "Auction": [
    {
      "A": 101322143.24,
      "B": 50243301.2,
      "C": 569,
      "D": "Auction"
    }
  ],
  "Sold Third Party": [
    {
      "A": 72000,
      "B": 93900,
      "C": 1,
      "D": "Sold Third Party"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here every value is JSONArray, because I am getting `Map<Object, List<Map<String, Object>>>`. Is there any way to get `Map<Object, Map<String, Object>>`collection using Stream API, So I can get a proper JSON (without JSONArray value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) instead:

```
salesReportForSoldProperty.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(tags -> tags.get("D"), Function.identity()));
```

Note that in this case if your input contains two elements with the same `"D"` value, you will got an `IllegalStateException` as you cannot put two values into the same map key. If you want to ignore duplicates, you may specify the merge function as third argument:

```
salesReportForSoldProperty.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(tags -> tags.get("D"), Function.identity(), (a, b) -> a));
```

Comment: Thank You Tagir. i will try it. Can you please tell me which package I need to import for using Function.identity() ?

Comment: @SonuGupta, `java.util.function`

Comment: Can we also trim white spaces and '-' form the keys of Map?

Comment: @SonuGupta, use regexp: `tags -> tags.get("D").replaceAll("[\\- ]", "")`

Comment: Thank You @Tagir I got it now, we can apply any operation on tags, I just need to cast it.

Comment: I have one more doubt, If input contains two elements with same key like "D", Is it possible to add its inner elements, Suppose my list is {
      "A": 50,
      "B": 100,
      "C": 150,
      "D": "Auction"
    },
    {
      "A": 200,
      "B": 300,
      "C": 400,
      "D": "Sold Third Party"
    }
and when JAVA Stream is grouping it , result should be like this
 
"Auction": 
    {
      "A": 250,
      "B": 300,
      "C": 550,
      "D": "Auction"
    }

Comment: @SonuGupta, possible, but comment space is too short for this. Ask another question.

Comment: Ok I will ask the question for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102493/discussion-between-sonu-gupta-and-tagir-valeev).